# How Do I model bind JSON to a List<string> ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization

I have a model in C# like this

```
 public class SendEmailModel
{
    public List<string> UsersToEmail { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public bool SendCopy { get; set; }
}
```

But when I pass the JSON in it does not bind to the List UsersToEmail but everything else works fine.

```
 public JsonResult SendEmail(SendEmailModel sem)
```

Is there something special that needs to be done to inform the model binding that there is a object in this class that is a List of strings ? Or should it be smart enough to pick this up automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. On the javascript side this piece was added.. once I removed it it works fine..

```
    data: fixedEncodeURI($.param(values)),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
```